# Display custom message on 'f.submit' for 'simple_form_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have a reset `password` page. When user updates his/her `password`, I want to display some additional wordings (a custom message). My `simple_form_for` has this submit button:

```
<%= f.submit :value => "Update", id: "password_reset",:class => 'btn btn-default fr' %>
```

How can I display a message with a click of this submit button?

Comment: What kind of message? Where do you want to display it? On the button itself? At the top of the page like a flash message? is it some kind of "Updating ..." message?

Comment: Yes like a flash msg.. and page is also redirecting to my root page so I want to display flash msg on that root page after redirect

Comment: You want the message after the update is successful OR right after the form is submitted?

Comment: after update is successful

Comment: Can you show the update action (where this form is submitted) and also the view for next page where user is redirected, along with the layout?